# Graphing a systems of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I'm trying to understand how to graph systems of linear equations.

Say for example we have the following:

$x_1 - 2x_2 = -1$

$-x_1 + 3x_2 = 3$

I'm only used to graphing $x$ and $y$ coordinates, how am I supposed to interpret these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace $x_1$ with $x$, $x_2$ with $y$. Names are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

The first equation can be written as
$$
x_2=\frac{1}2(x_1+1)
$$
and the second one:
$$
x_2=\frac13 x_1+1
$$

If you replace $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x$ and $y$ respectively, you will see something you are familiar with.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could

- Treat $x_2$ as $y$
- and $x_1$ as $x$
- so you are drawing

  - $x_2=\frac12x_1+\frac12$
  - $x_2=\frac13x_1+1$
- and label the axes appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Just set $x=x_1, y=x_2$, or when drawing the graph, label the axes $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of $x$ and $y$.
A solution is where the lines cross.